Summing build number and variable in GitHub Actions using windows runner
We are building a maui project in GitHubn Actions.
In order to increment the versionCode for android builds we use github.run_number + an offset, to keep it ahead of the version code deployed in Google Play.
    - name: Calculate version-code
      env: 
          VERSION: ${{ github.run_number }}
      run: |
          echo "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER_WITH_OFFSET=$(($VERSION+300))" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: Update build number in AndroidManifest.xml
      uses: damienaicheh/update-android-version-manifest-action@v1.0.0
      with:
        android-manifest-path: 'Project/Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        version-code: ${{ env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER_WITH_OFFSET }}
        version-name: '${{ steps.get_version_from_manifest.outputs.versionName }}'
        print-file: true

This has worked fine so far, with runs-on: macos-13.
To keep costs down, we changed to runs-on: windows-latest.
We've tried ubuntu runners as well, but it is not able to build maui-projects.
I've understood that because the Windows runners use another shell than ubuntu and mac, windows using pwsh. It requires another syntax on the shell execution.
We have changed to:
- name: Calculate version-code
      env: 
          VER: ${{ github.run_number }}
      run: |
          echo "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER_WITH_OFFSET=$(( $Env:VERSION+300 ))" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append

This sets the variable, but it concatinates the strings, rather than summing them making the result something like 103300 and not 403.
Is it possible to do an aritmetic operation and store it in an environment variable on the windows-runner?

You can change the shell in your version-code workflow step to bash (shell: bash) and just use the old syntax.

Setting the * shell: bash, as proposed by MrBean Bremen in the comment on the quesion, solves the issue.
 - name: Calculate version-code
      shell: bash
      env: 
          VERSION: ${{ github.run_number }}
      run: |
          echo "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER_WITH_OFFSET=$(($VERSION+100))" >> $GITHUB_ENV

